# Starting Xorg process on all installed GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, fancontrol

Specs:

```
4x GTX 1080
nVidia 390.25
Ubuntu Server 17.10
Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic
```

Goal: Headless system with the following fan control script running on boot:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1
nvidia-settings -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUFanControlState=1
nvidia-settings -a [fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:2]/GPUFanControlState=1
nvidia-settings -a [fan:2]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:3]/GPUFanControlState=1
nvidia-settings -a [fan:3]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100
```

Any one of these lines results in the following messages:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR The control display is undefined; please run 'nvidia-settings --help' for usage information
```

nvidia-smi reports no Xorg process running on any GPU, which is where the problem seems to lie. My guess is that one or more packages are missing or not set up correctly, though that doesn't narrow down my problem by much. Any ideas?

[See here for xorg.conf contents.](https://pastebin.com/w806p8JQ)

[See here for apt list --installed](https://pastebin.com/1G2p9b1e)

Comment: How did you install/configure X on this system? AFAIK ubuntu server doesn't have it installed natively, so there is likely some config that will need to manually be done after just installing the required packages.

Comment: I wish I had enough points to offer bounty on this question.